# Error when trying to increase storage on RDS MySQL instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I'm trying to increase the allocated storage from 2000GB to 2260GB (and IOPS from 6000 to 7000) on an RDS MySQL instance and I'm getting the following error message:

> null (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 500; Error Code: InternalFailure; Request ID: ea593451-3454-11e5-bc38-b7fa8a060cf1)

The read replica for this instance has had it's storage and IOPS increased, so that's not the issue.

Any ideas what might be causing this? If I've missed any key info, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: When these types of errors occur, it's best to either open an aws support ticket OR post on the aws forums (which AWS support does monitor and will reply to). They can likely help you with your specific issue with your specific database. There is no generic answer for this unfortunately, that SO can answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not reproducable; contact vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was caused by the fact that Memchached was one enabled in the options group that was assigned to the RDS instance that I was trying to increase storage for.

From AWS support engineer:

> You got in contact as you were unable to initiate a scale storage for your RDS instance olympus- you were receiving an internal error.
>
> After reviewing this further on my side I let you know that the following error was being reported:
>
> > The option 'MEMCACHED' cannot be deleted as instance olympus has Read Replica which has the MEMCACHED present.
>
> This has been brought up with the RDS team as an issue. They are aware of it and are working on a fix, unfortunately Im unable to give a timeframe on this.
>
> To workaround the issue I suggested:
>
> 1. Modify the instance so that the instance is using the default option group i.e. disable memcache
> 2. Then modify the allocated storage on the instance.
> 3. Once the scale is complete re-add the memcache option group

After carrying out the above suggested steps, I was able to resize the instance and all is well now.